# Can google's OAuth clientID be put directly in code?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, google-oauth

I'm doing Google login in React. Is it safe to put the clientId directly as a string in my js file, or do I have to use an .env file to keep it secret?

```
<GoogleLogin
        clientId={clientId}
        ...
/>
```

Answer (score 4):

As long as you dont expose your client Secret its okay , and as to your question no matter where you put you Client Id , in the build all of variables can be accessed it doesnt matter if its in .env or somewhere else .